# How to get the 2d position of the touch on screen in webXR(AR)

Tags: three.js, webxr

I'm trying to get the touch position on the Android device's screen when running the webXR app with Three.js.

I'm using https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/webxr/ARButton.js to detect the user touching on the screen and it works.

Here are relevant code lines:

```
document.body.appendChild(ARButton.createButton(this.renderer));
this.controller = this.renderer.xr.getController(0);
this.controller.addEventListener('select', (event) => this.onSelect(event));
this.scene.add(this.controller);

onSelect(event) {
  //how to get the 2d touch position on screen area?
}
```

How can I get the 2d touch position in `onSelect()` function?

Answer (score 0):

The touches property returns an array of Touch objects. Thus, you can access the touch coordinates by access the first array object.

```
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    touchDown=true;
    touchX = e.touches[0].pageX;
    touchY = e.touches[0].pageY;
    console.log(touchX, touchY);
}, false);
```